# Need to create two columns based on exiting column in data frame with some condition

Tags: python

I need to assign two columns (column 2 & column 3) to exiting data frame on basis of other column present in data frame( column 1).

i tried if & else condition but not succeed.

condition is:-

**for column 2** :- =IF(LEFT(D,5)="=====","BLANK",IF(LEFT(D,5)="*****","BLANK",IF(LEFT(D,5)="Check","check",IF(LEFT(D,5)="-----","BLANK",IF(D<>"",LEFT(D,(FIND("]",D,1))),"BLANK")))))

**for column 1:-**
=IF(C="CHECK",D,IF(LEFT(C,1)="[",B))

above mention (C & D) are columns name of Column 1

Comment: python, really, or Excel???

Comment: actually i explain condition in excel. but i need implement this in python.

Answer (score 0):

All the syntax you need should be in the following sample code (I didn't check I used the if else in the right order):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["====="], ["CHECK"], ["[TEST"]])
df.columns=['A']
df['B'] = np.where((df["A"] == "=====") | (df["A"].str.startswith('[')), "blank", "check")
```

See more details at:
[Selecting with complex criteria from pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe)
[Python 3 Pandas Select Dataframe using Startswith + or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249152/python-3-pandas-select-dataframe-using-startswith-or)
[vectorize conditional assignment in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896769/vectorize-conditional-assignment-in-pandas-dataframe)